# How to make a packageSource in a nuget.config file optional?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a nuget.config file (in my asp.net core project) which points to a local share on our company network for custom nuget packages.

However, when I am working from home, that address is not available.

I can see a number of options, including...

- create an environment variable for the reference to our local feed
- host the packages in azuredevops
- have a custom nuget.config files

But ideally I'd like a zero config solution which I can check into source control. Something like adding a packageSource with an "optional" attribute and let dotnet restore figure out where it can get packages from. But there isn't an optional attribute and dotnet restore fails if it can't connect to the package source.

Is a zero config solution possible?

Comment: Nope. It works that way by design because there are scenarios where it will change the packages restored depending on if the source is there or not. Build reliability/integrity is considered more important.

Comment: many thanks - I hadn't considered that.